# print the pattern as per the given input array , input[2,4,1,6]

Tags: php, arrays

Just want to print the pattern by giving input through array

```
<?php
$a=array(2,4,1,6);
foreach($a as $a1){
for($row=1;$row<=count($a1);$row++){
   for($col=1;$col<=count($a1);$col++){
       echo "*";
   } 
   echo "<br>";
 }
}
?>
```

I'm using foreach loop to pass the values one by one  but that's not working?

Comment: What is the expected pattern output for `input[2,4,1,6]`

Comment: it seems like a homework

Comment: Your array is one-dimension. So when looping `$a` your `count($a1)` is always not valid, because `$a1` is 2, 4, 1, and finally 6

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_pad to avoid all the excessive looping.

```
$a = array(2,4,1,6);

foreach($a as $a1){

    echo str_pad("", $a1, "*") . "<br/>\n";

}
```

https://3v4l.org/INTAl

Comment: What about `str_repeat`?

Comment: Pretty much the same thing, I usually use the function that gives me the most flexibility. With str_pad you can have an input and define if it's right or left pad.

Answer (score 0):

below can be used to achieve your expected outcome. (Assuming that the the pattern you want to create is given as the input array)

```
$a=array(2,4,1,6);
foreach($a as $a1){
  for($col=1;$col<=$a1;$col++){
   echo "*";
  } 
 echo "<br>";
}
```

I want to print the mirror image some what like this
        *
        *
      * *
      * *
      * *
     ** *
     ****

Comment: What does the line `for($row=1;$row<=count($a1);$row++)` actually do?

Answer (score 0):

`count($a1)` will always == `1`.

In the `foreach` loop `$a1` will take the values of the members of the array, so `$a1 == 2` on the first loop, `4` on the second, and so on. `$a1` is a number, so using `count($a1)` doesn't make any sense.

The second loop (the `for` loop) is presumably to print the same number of asterisks as the value of `$a1`. The *value* remember, not the *count*, the count is how many members an array or object has. So instead of `$row<=count($a1)` you need to use `row<=$a1`.

The third loop is unnecessary. Unless you're printing in 3 dimensions. Just move the `print` function inside the first `for` loop and delete it.